# How to capture press and hold (long press) of the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The keydown documentation states that the keydown will be sent again if it's held down, but if you hold down the media key I don't get any notification at all. Is there a way to detect this? It's actually going to a Google (Now?) Search voice-input - perhaps there's a broadcast indicating that is happening I could receive?

Here's my `BroadcastReceiver`'s receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    int SoundID = 0;

    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction))
    {
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event != null)
        {               
            int action = event.getAction();

            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                Log.d("Hi", "MEDIA keydown r" + event.getRepeatCount());

                if (event.getRepeatCount() == 1)
                    DoSomethingMagical();
                else if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
                    DoSomethingSpecial();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can react on the long press event by adding the following `intent-filter` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.speech.action.WEB_SEARCH"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Unfortunately this will not be handled in the same way as an action of type `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` (your `BroadcastReceiver` won't be invoked).